# Expect object length to be null

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, angular-test

I have the following Object where I need to test it to be null:

```
  getLastTeamUpdatedItemLogBuffer(): IBufferElement {
const storageItems = this.storageSvc.getItem(StorageKey.lastTeamUpdatedItem, true) as IBufferElement;
return storageItems || null;
```

}

Here is IbufferElement:

```
export interface IBufferElement {
  timestamp: number;
  text: string;
}
```

**I succeed** in testing return **storageItems** but I can't do it on return null
Here is return storageItems:

```
it('should return value from storage, if available', () => {
  storageSvc.getItem = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue([{}, {}]);
  expect(Object.keys(service.getLastTeamUpdatedItemLogBuffer()).length).toBe(2);
});
```

**Here is what I'm trying for return null but it's not working:**

```
it('should return empty, if storage value is null', () => {
  storageSvc.getItem = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue([]);
  expect(Object.keys(service.getLastTeamUpdatedItemLogBuffer()).length).toBe(0);
});
```

I also tried it with "toBeFalsy()" or "toBe(null)" and returnValue(null) or returnValue([null]) but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's the error? Expect 1 to be 0?

Comment: @AliF50 I don't get any error for expect(Object.keys(service.getLastTeamUpdatedItemLogBuffer()).length).toBe(0);, but in code coverage when I hover the null yellow value is saying "branch not covered".
For .toBe(null); I get  Error: Expected 0 to be null

Comment: Yes, I think the `|| null` is not covered. To cover it, do `storageSvc.getItem = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(undefined);` and then `expect(service.getLastTeamUpdatedItemLogBuffer()).toBeNull();`.

Comment: I tried like that @AliF50. Now is saying: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: You removed the `Object.keys` right? If you did, then I am not sure, sorry.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to remove object.keys. It's working now, thanks a lot! Can you answer Question (the button below) so I guess I can give you give you the right answer appreciation button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `|| null` is not covered.

To cover it, do:

```
storageSvc.getItem = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(undefined); and then expect(service.getLastTeamUpdatedItemLogBuffer()).toBeNull();
```